# When to commit application settings to SharedPreferences (onStop or onDestroy)

Tags: android

I was wondering, when is the suitable time to save our application settings to SharedPreferences. Should we do it during `onStop`, or `onDestroy`? I realize both methods have their pros and cons.

### onStop

If user intention is not quitting the application, save application settings to SharedPreferences just seem to be redundant. He merely **press home** (onStop called) -> **long press home** -> **relaunch application by select the application again**

### onDestroy

User can *kill* the application by **press home** (onStop called) -> **long press home** -> **swipe left on the application to kill it**. If user quit the application by that way, I realize `onDestroy` is not being called although the app is *killed*. Hence, application settings is not being saved.

So, is it better to save the application settings, during `onStop` or `onDestroy`?

Comment: Also if the Activity is in the background the OS may kill it at anytime, in this case neither `onStop()` nor `onDestroy()` will be called, as stated below `onPause()` is the safest "clean up" method to use.

Comment: Related bug report: [Conflicting guidance for when to save](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=232981)

Comment: @EdwardBrey Thanks. Seem pretty tricky. Time-consuming save operation should be done in `onStop`, but `onStop` is not guaranteed to be called...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is best to call `commit()` either right after you've made the changes, or in the `onPause()` method. This ensures that your changes are saved in pretty much every scenario, except uncaught exceptions that crash your app.

Also, you should note that neither `onStop()` or `onDestroy()` are guaranteed to be called at all, particularly in situations when Android is low on memory. However, `onPause()` is almost always called.

Comment: After API level 8, there is also the apply() method that does its work in the background.  A better choice if you are not relying on the result being used right away. 

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()

Comment: It begs the question, why do all the Google examples use `onStop()` intead of `onPause()`, I've personally always used `onPause()` myself, but noticed a few `SO` posts today suggesting `onStop()` also. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: On the other hand, `onPause()` is called before creating the next activity, thus delaying its creation until it ends, and `onStop()` is called after the next activity is launched and displayed.

Comment: The lifecycle guide says "you should not use onPause() to save application or user data". Perhaps it assumes you are using a blocking version, though.

Answer (score 0):

I Think Android documentation explains pretty much when you should be comiting or persisting any data from user:

> onPause() is where you deal with the user leaving your activity. Most
>   importantly, any changes made by the user should at this point be
>   committed (usually to the ContentProvider holding the data).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Comment: on the other hand (from http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html): Generally, you should not use onPause() to store user changes to permanent storage. The only time you should persist user changes to permanent storage within onPause() is when you're certain users expect the changes to be auto-saved. However, you should avoid performing CPU-intensive work during onPause(), such as writing to a database, because it can slow the visible transition to the next activity (you should instead perform heavy-load shutdown operations during onStop()).